# Export HTML Table to Excel in SharePoint Online in IE using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I need to export a HTML table to Excel (or a CSV) that is in SharePoint Online in IE. Is there a way to do this all client side with jQuery, or do I need some server side activity? If so, how would I do this. I have seen this article, but since it's SharePoint Online, I need some help getting started.

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/04/export-table-to-excel-jquery-ie.html

Thanks!

Comment: Is a jQuery solution needed? Doesn't IE already have a proprietary "Export to Excel" feature built in? When using IE, normally you can right-click anywhere within the table's cells and one of the options in the menu will be "Export to Excel".

Comment: It doesn't pull in the dynamic data. I am using the tabletools plugin for datatables and am all set. Thanks!